# React storybook. Declaration or statement expected

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have the following story, and i simply decided to add another element to it.

So the default one was:

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { actions } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import { withSmartKnobs } from 'storybook-addon-smart-knobs';
import { StarRating } from 'components';
import centered from '@storybook/addon-centered/react';


const stories = storiesOf('FORMS|StarRating', module);
const eventsFromNames = actions('onClick');
const strings = { labelText: 'texto de prueba' };

stories
  .addDecorator(withSmartKnobs)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .addDecorator(centered)
  .add('Default', () => (<StarRating counter={5} />));
```

But i tried adding another story like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { actions } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { withKnobs } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';
import { withSmartKnobs } from 'storybook-addon-smart-knobs';
import { StarRating } from 'components';
import centered from '@storybook/addon-centered/react';


const stories = storiesOf('FORMS|StarRating', module);
const eventsFromNames = actions('onClick');
const strings = { labelText: 'texto de prueba' };

stories
  .addDecorator(withSmartKnobs)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .addDecorator(centered)
  .add('Default', () => (<StarRating counter={5} />));
  .add('Fixed', () => (<StarRating iconsNumber={5} isDisabled={true} readOnly={true} />));
```

But all that im receiving is

> Declaration or statement expected.

[image]

Hwat am i missing? This is how i always used to add stories as far as i know.

Comment: .add('Default', () => (<StarRating counter={5} />)); - remove semicolon

Comment: I still dont see the story tho. I can only see the old one